# Slick2D Easiest Way Of Positioning Images Using GameContainer.setDisplayMode(GameContainer.getScreenWidth(), GameContainer.getScreenHight(), true);

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm making a game in slick2D and i wanted the game to adjust resolutions acording to the screen being used, so when i initialize my AppGameContainer i call it as the following shows

```
AppGameContainer appgc;
try{
appgc = new AppGameContainer(appgc.getScreenWidth(), appgc.getScreenHeight(), true);

}catch....
```

So my question is when using this method will i have to draw objects and do collision detection using appgc.getScreenWidth() and appgc.getScreenWidth() for example if i wanted to draw a square in the middle of the screen would i have to do it like so ?

```
g.fillRect(appgc.getScreenWidth, appgc.getScreenHeight(), 50, 50);
```

or is there some easier way around this, as this could get confusing with  collision later on as opposed to just an X and a Y axis?

thanks for any helpful answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw a square in the middle of the screen using fillRect you have to do that :

int square_width = 50 ;
int  = 50 ;

```
g.fillRect((appgc.getScreenWidth+square_width)/2, (appgc.getScreenHeight+square_height)/2, square_width, square_height);
```

Indeed there is the function :

> fillRect(float x1, float y1, float width, float height)
>
> - x1 - The x coordinate of the top left corner
> - y1 - The y coordinate of the top left corner
> - width - The width of the rectangle to fill
> - height - The height of the rectangle to fill